# MySQL not able to execute INSERT INTO [table]. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to pull information from an HTML form and put this into a database using the following code:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "MyDB");

if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO interest (name, email, dob, address) 
        VALUES ('$fullname', '$email', '$dob' '$addr')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
}else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

It was working, and I've managed to get 2 test runs in, but now I'm getting the following error at the top of my submission page

> ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO MyDB (name, email, dob,
>   address) VALUES ('test name', 'test@email.com', '2003-02-01'
>   'address'). Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I have another variant of this which sends a PHP email, which is the file I'm using to base this database connection on.

There is also an autoincrement on ID column which is set as the primary key in the database if that makes a difference? SQL isn't my strong point unfortunately!

Comment: so where are these coming from? `$fullname', '$email', '$dob' '$addr'` and do they hold values? http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php Edit: ok, you do have values, but it's a syntax error. Missing a comma and is ***Off-topic.***

Comment: Nice injection you have there. Enjoy your server being pawned.

Answer (score 5):

Given the syntax error you have in your query, being a missing comma in `'$dob' '$addr'`; you are open to an SQL injection and should be using a prepared statement.

- Therefore, I am submitting this complementary answer for your own safety.

Here is an example of a prepared statement using the MySQLi API.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'my_db');

if (!$link) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// assuming these are the POST arrays taken from your HTML form if you're using one.
$fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$dob = $_POST['dob'];
$addr = $_POST['addr'];

   $sql = ("INSERT INTO interest (name, email, dob, address) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

    $stmt = $link->prepare($sql) or die("Failed Execution");
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $fullname, $email, $dob, $addr);

    $stmt->execute();
    echo $stmt->error;

echo "SUCCESS";

    exit();
```

References:

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
- http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

---

**Foonotes:**

If using the following failed because of the AI'd column:

```
$sql = ("INSERT INTO interest (name, email, dob, address) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

You may also try: (I used `id` as the AI'd column as an example)

```
$sql = ("INSERT INTO interest (id, name, email, dob, address) VALUES ('', ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

This could be the case, as I have seen this type of SQL failure behaviour before.

Comment: Thank you - I'll give this a go and see how I get on. 
I do know a little about SQL Injection but I've only recently started working with PHP and SQL to this extent. 
I'll do a bit more research next time before making myself look a fool haha

Answer (score 2):

You have missed comma here:

```
VALUES ('$fullname', '$email', '$dob' '$addr')
```

Thus (as it was clearly said in error text) column count doesn't mach values count.

It should be

```
VALUES ('$fullname', '$email', '$dob', '$addr')
```

Comment: Given your probable SQL experience, you should make note that you're still leaving them open to an SQL injection. If you're going to go after low-hanging fruit like that (off-topic syntax error, btw), at the very least give them a safer solution.

Comment: @Fred-ii- PHP is not my "native" programming language, so I can't construct parameterized query for `mysqli_query` without reading documentation. If you can do it - I think your suggestion will be useful to the question author.

Comment: This isn't PHP, it's MySQL, *2 different animals altogether*. ;-)

Comment: Ah ok Andy. I see you're quite strong in C ;-) *Cheers*

Answer (score 2):

You missed a comma

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO interest (name, email, dob, address) 
        VALUES ('$fullname', '$email', '$dob', '$addr')";
                                             ^here
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a comma:

```
VALUES ('$fullname', '$email', '$dob' '$addr')
```